# How to increase the amount of times one can use REDO option?

Tags: actions

Can the number of redos be increased? My limit is like 5 and I need at least 100 because I am new to this and mess up ALL THE TIME. I tried ... [EDIT] [PREFERENCES] [INPUT] but can't seem to find how to solve this. Anybody know?

Comment: Welcome to Blender stack exchange. Did you try looking in the System tab in the preferences window? There is a tab for Memory and Limits with Undo Steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you mean by any chance UNDO steps?

They can be increased here:
*Edit > Preferences > System > Undo steps*

[image]

The maximum is 256, but that should be enough in most cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot... was looking in the wrong places.